# attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value: Lua error message

Tags: lua, gideros

```
stage:addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, 
function()
Graphic:setRotation(Graphic:getRotation()+ (Timer.delayedCall(math.random(4, 8) , 
function () speed = math.random(1, 30) 
return speed
end)
))
end)
```

Basicallu, what I am trying to do is, change the speed of rotation randomly, but since I do not want it to change at every second, I tried using Timer.delayedCall in Gideros, but it gives an error that says `attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value: Lua error message`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Gideros documentation, Timer.delayedCall returns a 'Timer' object, which should be the table the error message is referring to. 
http://docs.giderosmobile.com/reference/gideros/Timer/delayedCall

I'm not intimately familiar with Gideros but I believe you would want something closer to this:

```
stage:addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, 
    function()
        Timer.delayedCall(math.random(4,8), 
            function()
                Graphic:setRotation( Graphic:getRotation() + math.random(1,30) )
            end)
    end)
```

However, this will presumably still fire with every ENTER_FRAME event, just that each change will be delayed randomly. You may want to use a control variable so that only one Timer can be pending:

```
local timerPending=false
stage:addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, 
    function()
        if timerPending then return end
        timerPending=true
        Timer.delayedCall(math.random(4,8), 
            function()
                Graphic:setRotation( Graphic:getRotation() + math.random(1,30) )
                timerPending=false
            end)
    end)
```

Comment: I got your point, but don't you think timerpending will just add an extra condition check since the above code delayed the rotation randomly or may be I am not able to understand the fine purpose of timerpending ?